# hmac authentication in vcl

Tags: url, varnish, hmac, varnish-vcl

I am trying to authenticate URL using hamc. I can do the following to verify.My question is how do I parse the URL to extract only part of the URL excluding the hmac parameter. I tried using local variables in vcl but it threw an error. 
Any suggestions on how to extract the hmac value and URL query parameters as shown below.

```
http://localhost/zzz/?q1=xxx&q2=yyy&hmac=hash

if (digest.hmac_md5("key", "q1=xxx&q2=yyy") != "value")
      {
          return (synth(401, digest.hmac_md5("key", "http://localhost/zzz/?q1=xxx&q2=yyy")));
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for a external plugin in that case you can just strip out the `hmac=XXX` query string parameter, from `req.url`  and store the result in a new variable `req.http.url_without_hmac`  and `req.http.hmac` to the `digest.hmac_md5`

see a sample test case:

```
varnishtest "Strip query parameter"

server s1 {
       rxreq
       txresp
       rxreq
       txresp

} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    import std;

    sub vcl_recv {
      # Strip out HMAC parameter

    # get only the query string, ignore uri
    set req.http.qs = regsuball(req.url, ".*\?(.*?)$", "?\1");

    # strip hmac= from the qs
    set req.http.url_without_hmac = regsuball(req.http.qs,"\?hmac=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?hmac=AAA"
    set req.http.url_without_hmac = regsuball(req.http.url_without_hmac,"\?hmac=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?hmac=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.http.url_without_hmac = regsuball(req.http.url_without_hmac,"&hmac=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&hmac=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&hmac=AAA&bar=baz"

    # remove the leading ? from the url_without_hmac
    set req.http.url_without_hmac = regsuball(req.http.url_without_hmac,"^\?(.*)$", "\1");

    # extract the hmac= value from the req.http.qs
    set req.http.hmac = regsuball(req.http.qs, ".*[?&]hmac=([^&]*).*", "\1");
    # NOW USE req.http.url_without_hmac for your digest validation and req.http.hmac as the value


    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        set resp.http.url_without_hmac = req.http.url_without_hmac;
        set resp.http.hmac = req.http.hmac;
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq  -url "/1?a=1&hmac=2&b=1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.url_without_hmac ==  "a=1&b=1"
    expect resp.http.hmac ==   "2"


} -run


client c2 {
    txreq  -url "/1?hmac=hello&a=1&b=1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.url_without_hmac ==  "a=1&b=1"
    expect resp.http.hmac ==  "hello"


} -run
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `[querystring][1]` vmod. As far as I know it does not come pre-packaged, so you will need to build it but it should do exactly what you need.

With that you can define regexes/static values to match querystring arguments, and then filter those out or in.